# Array filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I need to make a filter that searches the following array of objects and filters out those objects whose `ID` value is equal to a `Message` value in any of those objects in the array. Also the filter should return only objects with `level` equal to `1`. I've already managed to filter the `level` property, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the rest.

Let's consider an example: `ID: 001` contains in its `Message` `006`, so I want to filter out all objects, whose `ID` is `006`.

```
$scope.myData = [
{
   "ID" : "001",
   "Message" : "006",
   "level":"1"
},
{
   "ID" : "002",
   "Message" : "test test test test1",
   "level":"1"

},
{
   "ID" : "003",
   "Message" : "test test test test",
   "level":"1"

},
{
   "ID" : "004",
   "Message" : "test test test test",
   "level":"1"
},
{
   "ID" : "005",
   "Message" : " My Test",
   "level":"1"

},
{
   "ID" : "006",
   "Message" : "",
   "level":"1"

},
{
   "ID" : "007",
   "Message" : "next level",
   "level":"2"

}

];
})
```

And filter:

```
app.filter('filterData3', function () {
return function (data) {
    var dataToBePushed = [];
    data.forEach(function (resultData) {
        if (resultData.level == 1)
            dataToBePushed.push(resultData);
    });
    return dataToBePushed;
}
});
```

Comment: so you need to return any two objects that has some fields in common?

Comment: that would not filter out the record of 006.. that is also in level 1

Comment: no I need to filter out that record that has some fields in common

Comment: do you mean that the resultant array should have unique objects?

Comment: yes you are correct.. the array should be also be in the same level:1

Comment: so if there is any message that matches another ID in some other object, the other object must be removed right?

Comment: yes, so the 001 record would remain in the array, and the 006 must be removed..

Comment: So you basically want to return just the first matched object? In your question it's really confusing what you want to achieve, can you show some example of your HTML as well.

Comment: Explain in your question clearly what query would you want to use against the data set and what it should return.

Comment: you need to clarify more please, I was in the process of writing some points that would help, but another questions aroused so ...

Comment: No I want to return the entire array without the matched value in it.. ... what should be returned is : ID's 001,002,003,004,005 .... 006 should not be returned because it is referenced in the message of 001, and 007 is not returned because of the level of 2( which the filter already does that).. The HTML is; <li ng-repeat=" datax in myData| filterData3">

Comment: So what is your query? You want to return all items that are on level 1 and don't have an empty message?

Comment: No I do not care about the message, I just do not want 006 to show on my html page.. I have other information that will not have value in the message and they need to show up, but if the (for example) 006(or other numerical number( I do not know what they would be)) is specified in the message field, then the 006(or the unknown numbers) record would be filtered out of the array and of course are on the same level

Comment: That's a better explanation, edit your question for better understading for other readers. Also I believe the answer below answers that question already, but you should edit it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to **NOT** include in your filtered array the elements which ID is contained in another element's Message, you could write a filter like the following:

```
.filter('filterData3', function () {
return function (data) {
    var dataToBePushed = [];
    var messages =[];
    data.forEach(function (resultData) {
        if (resultData.level == 1 && (messages.indexOf(resultData.ID) == -1)) {
            messages.push(resultData.Message);
            dataToBePushed.push(resultData);
        }   
    });
    return dataToBePushed;
}})
```

Hope this works for you